# how to use AddDllDirectory() function to add dll locations for load-time dynamic linking

Tags: c++, dll, compilation

I have an application that has the following structure:

```
app dir
...exe dir
......app.exe
......somedll1.dll
......somedll2.dll
...subdir1
......subdir1_dll1.dll
......subdir1_dll2.dll
...subdir2
......subdir2_dll1.dll
......subdir2_dll2.dll
```

Due to how the app.exe works (which I cannot change as it's closed source), it searches for the dll1 in each subdir, but not the dll2. I would need to place the dll2 into the exe dir, but this introduces problems:

1. Each subdir dll1 loads the dll2, and each need their own memory, so I cannot share the memory of dll2 between each dll1.
2. While currently the dll2 of each subdir is the same, there is no guarantee that will be the same in the future
3. Even if it shared memory was a possibility, due to project specifics, it's less intuitive and elegant to place the dll in exe dir.

Given these issues, I'm trying to use the libloaderapi.h function AddDllDirectory in each dll1 to specify where to search for the dll2. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to use it. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-adddlldirectory) say:

```
DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE AddDllDirectory(
  [in] PCWSTR NewDirectory
);
```

> An absolute path to the directory to add to the search path. For
> example, to add the directory Dir2 to the process DLL search path,
> specify \Dir2

But I can't get to use it correctly. If I define the function and in the next line call it:

```
DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE AddDllDirectory(
    PCWSTR NewDirectory
);

AddDllDirectory(("c:\\"));
```

I get various warnings in the `DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE AddDllDirectory` line :

```
Can't find definition for AddDllDirectory
Declaration is not compatible with "int AddDllDirectory(<error-type>)"
C28251: Incoherent annotation for AddDllDirectory. This instance has no annotations.
```

And many errors in the `AddDllDirectory(("c:\\"));` line:

```
Missing ")" before "("
Missing ")" before string
Function returns a function
...
```

Even removing the call to the function yields error, simply including this line in the code:

```
DLL_DIRECTORY_COOKIE AddDllDirectory(
    PCWSTR NewDirectory
);
```

Already gives the following warnings:

```
C28251: Incoherent annotation for AddDllDirectory. This instance has no annotations.
```

And when compiling, the following warnings:

```
warning C4273: 'AddDllDirectory': incoherent dll linking
message : look at the previous definition of 'AddDllDirectory'
```

I tried to look for examples online but none seem to work.

I am using `#include <libloaderapi.h>` and `#include <windows.h>`

Comment: First, you don't need to declare `AddDllDirectory()` manually, it is already declared in the Win32 API for you, `#include <Windows.h>` will suffice to use it. And second, you are trying to call the Unicode version of `AddDllDirectory()` passing it an ANSI string.  Use `L"c:\\"` instead of `("c:\\")`

Comment: managed to make it work at then end, the point I was missing is what you said about not needing to manually re-declare the function. The C docs are not very intuitive. What I'm having trouble now with is that I'm getting the relative path of my subdir dll1 using GetModuleHandleEx, _splitpath and _makepath, and the string returned by the last fucntion doesn't seem to work nicely with AddDllDirectory. Any pointers? I'm trying to make use of mbstowcs, but I'm struggling to make it work, and I still get the paths with a single backlash

Comment: Don't use relative paths, only absolute paths. And since `AddDllDirectory()` requires a Unicode string, use `GetModuleHandleExW()`, `_wsplitpath()`, and `_wmakepath()` instead.

Comment: oh that's great! I know it's more secure in many aspects to use absolute paths, I'll switch to that in production code, but for development, using absolute paths means that I have to compile the C dll, then change the absolute path to other subdir, recompile it, change absolute path again, etc. Too many steps for a project I'm potentially compiling 20 times an hour

Comment: "*using absolute paths means that I have to compile the C dll, then change the absolute path to other subdir, recompile it, change absolute path again, etc*" - then you clearly have the wrong idea about how paths work, because that is certainly NOT necessary. Using the functions I mentioned earlier, DLL1 can obtain its own absolute path *at runtime* and *modify* it as needed (ie, drop the filename) to *create* an absolute path to the desired folder *relative to DLL1*, then pass that modified path to `AddDllDirectory()`.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant and I intended to do using the modules I mentioned (but thanks for the heads up about the wide character version of GetModuleHandleEx). The point is to build an absolute path relative to where the C dll lies. What I meant is that, if I don't do that, I would have to hardcode the absolute path to the subdirs dlls, and compile the C dll once for every subdir dll